# c++ date difference between two dates

Tags: c++, string, function, date

I'm trying to make a function that reads two dates and chooses the bigger one, and then gets the difference in days. I've tried a lot so far but sometimes the answer is incorrect.
I can't find where the problem is. Can anyone help me find the problem, and/or give some advice on how to debug this kind of problem?

```
#include < iostream >
#include < string.h >
#include < string>
#include < cstdlib >
#include < sstream >
using namespace std;
int period(string days1, string months1, string years1, string days2,string months2, string years2)
{
int periodday, periodmonth, periodyear, periodindays,
year1 = atof(years1.c_str()), month1 = atof(months1.c_str()),
day1 = atof(days1.c_str()), year2 = atof(years2.c_str()),
month2 = atof(months2.c_str()), day2 = atof(days2.c_str());
int biggeryear, smalleryear, biggermonth, smallermonth, biggerday, smallerday;
if (year1 > year2) {
    biggeryear = year1;
    biggermonth = month1;
    biggerday = day1;
    smalleryear = year2;
    smallermonth = month2;
    smallerday = day2;
    }
else {
    biggeryear = year2;
    biggermonth = month2;
    biggerday = day2;
    smalleryear = year1;
    smallermonth = month1;
    smallerday = day1;
}
if (year1 == year2) {
    if (month1 > month2) {
        biggeryear = year1;
        biggermonth = month1;
        biggerday = day1;
        smalleryear = year2;
        smallermonth = month2;
        smallerday = day2;
    }
    else {
        biggeryear = year2;
        biggermonth = month2;
        biggerday = day2;
        smalleryear = year1;
        smallermonth = month1;
        smallerday = day1;
    }
    if (month1 == month2) {
        if (day1 > day2) {
            biggeryear = year1;
            biggermonth = month1;
            biggerday = day1;
            smalleryear = year2;
            smallermonth = month2;
            smallerday = day2;
        }
        else {
            biggeryear = year2;
            biggermonth = month2;
            biggerday = day2;
            smalleryear = year1;
            smallermonth = month1;
            smallerday = day1;
        }
    }
}
periodday = biggerday - smallerday;
periodmonth = biggermonth - smallermonth;
periodyear = biggeryear - smalleryear;
if (periodday < 0) {
    periodmonth = periodmonth - 1;
    if (biggermonth == 1 || biggermonth == 3 || biggermonth == 5 ||
    biggermonth == 7 || biggermonth == 8 | biggermonth == 12 ||
    biggermonth == 10) {
        periodday += 31;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 4 || biggermonth == 6 || biggermonth == 9 ||
    biggermonth == 11) {
        periodday += 30;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 2 && biggeryear == 0) {
        periodday += 28;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 1 && biggeryear % 4 != 0) {
        periodday += 29;
    }
}
if (periodmonth < 0) {
    periodyear--;
    if (biggermonth == 1 || biggermonth == 3 || biggermonth == 5 ||
    smallermonth == 7 || biggermonth == 8 || biggermonth == 12 ||
    biggermonth == 10)
    {
        periodmonth = periodmonth + 12;
        periodmonth = abs(periodmonth) * 31;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 4 || biggermonth == 6 || biggermonth == 9 ||
    biggermonth == 11) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth + 12;
        periodmonth = abs(periodmonth) * 30;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 2 && biggeryear % 4 == 0) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth + 12;
        periodmonth = abs(periodmonth) * 28;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 2 && biggeryear % 4 != 0) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth + 12;
        periodmonth = abs(periodmonth) * 29;
    }
}
else if (periodmonth >= 0) {
    if (biggermonth == 1 || biggermonth == 3 || biggermonth == 5 ||
    biggermonth == 7 || biggermonth == 8 || biggermonth == 12 ||
    biggermonth == 10) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth * 31;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 4 || biggermonth == 6 || biggermonth == 9 ||
    biggermonth == 11) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth * 30;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 2 && biggeryear % 4 == 0) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth * 28;
    }
    if (biggermonth == 2 && biggeryear % 4 != 0) {
        periodmonth = periodmonth * 29;
    }
}
if (periodyear < 0) {
    if (year1 % 4 != 0 || year2 % 4 != 0) {
        periodyear = year2 - year1;
        periodyear *= 366;
    }
    else {
        periodyear = year2 - year1;
        periodyear *= 365;
    }
}
else if (periodyear >= 0) {
    if (year1 % 4 != 0 || year2 % 4 != 0) {
        periodyear *= 366;
    }
    else {
        periodyear *= 365;
    }
}
periodindays = periodday + periodmonth + periodyear;
return abs(periodindays);
}
int main()
{
    string daya = ("1"), montha = ("1"), yeara = ("2016"), yearb = ("2016"),
    monthb = ("4"), dayb = ("27");
    int difference;
    difference = period(daya, montha, yeara, dayb, monthb, yearb);
    cout << difference << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Edit your post to have the correct indentations - or no one will even take you serious on this site lol. If you do that, I can look at what's going on.

Comment: add the input for which it failed and for which it passed.

Comment: Yusha I don't understand you

Comment: The date I tried gave me difference 116 while it should be 118

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, adding a sample of the data to be loaded, so people can test your use-case would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing things a bit complicated. My suggestion would be to convert your dates to a time_t value by setting the appropriate fields in a struct tm and using mktime(). You can then use difftime() to calculate the difference in seconds between the two dates.